# Создание серверов sql

Tags: sql-server, sql

Привет. 
В Sql Man.Studio создал пользователя root. 
Теперь пробую войти через "Проверку подлености SQL SERVER" . 
Что вводить в поле имя сервера?
Как создать/посмотреть созданные ранее сервера ?  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Откройте список.
Сервер создается при установке.

Если вы хотите подключиться к удаленному серверу, используйте его IP-адрес и порт.